# Show documents in a mobile WebBrowser control WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

i am working on an business mobile app that works with timesheets, and an all general workflow like accepting and creating documents.

now on one page there is a list op attachments that is shown, and what i want to do is when the user clicks on the attachment it should open up in a webbrowser control. The thing is, it wont always be a PNG, or JPG, it can be a word document or a powerpoint presentation.

so what i did, after getting the attachment from the webservice, i call this function.

```
 public static string GetMimeType(string fileExt)
        {
            //fileExt.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty();
            //fileExt = fileExt.TrimStart('.');
            fileExt = Path.GetExtension(fileExt);
            switch (fileExt)
            {
                case ".jpeg":
                case ".gif":
                case ".png":
                case ".tiff":
                case ".bmp":
                    return "image/" + fileExt;

                case ".jpg":
                    return "image/jpeg";

                case ".tif":
                    return "image/tiff";

                case ".htm":
                case ".html":
                case ".shtml":
                    return "text/html";

                case ".js":
                    return "text/javascript";

                case ".csv":
                case ".css":
                case ".sgml":
                    return "text/" + fileExt;

                case ".txt":
                    return "text/plain";

                case ".wav":
                    return "audio/wav";

                case ".mp3":
                    return "audio/mpeg3";

                case ".mid":
                    return "audio/midi";

                case ".qt":
                case ".mov":
                    return "video/quicktime";

                case ".mpg":
                    return "video/mpeg";

                case ".avi":
                    return "video/" + fileExt;

                case ".rtf":
                    return "application/" + fileExt;

                case ".xls":
                    return "application/x-excel";

                case ".docx":
                case ".doc":
                    return "application/msword";

                case ".ppt":
                    return "application/powerpoint";

                case ".gz":
                case ".tgz":
                    return "application/x-compressed";

                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Unknown fileExt: " + fileExt);
            }
        }
```

and then i get the type of document it is.

now here is where i have no idea what to do with that... how would i use the mimetype and name of attachment to tell the webbrowser control to show the attachment in appropriate way.

this is what i have so far on the page load of the webbrowser control.

```
 string imagename = WorkflowBase.ViewModel_WFPOSDocument.POSDocument.AttachmentList[0].FileName.ToString();
        string image = WorkflowBase.ViewModel_WFPOSDocument.POSDocument.AttachmentList[0].Attachment.ToString();
        string imagelink = WorkflowBase.ViewModel_WFPOSDocument.POSDocument.AttachmentList[0].AttachmentLink.ToString();

        string imagemimetype = AccTech.Helpers_and_Extensions.MimeTypes.GetMimeType(imagename);
        MyViewer.IsScriptEnabled = true;
        MyViewer.DataContext = this;



        MyViewer.Source = new Uri(URL, UriKind.Relative);
```

myviewer is the webbrowser control.

need anything else, just say the word.

i have no idea how to do this, any links, advice or code would be appreciated
im still a junior developer.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible on windows phone to show attachment throug webview, seeing that internet explorer deactivated all ativex controls.

so i used the [LauncFileAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701465.aspx) class to get the native viewer to open up the attachment!

hope this will help people who tried the same as me :)